# How do you fetch the attribute names of an Active Directory user objectClass without an instance of a user?

Tags: c#, active-directory

Essentially I would like to query the *schema* of the user objectClass just so I know all the possible attribute names a user object *could* have, but I don't want to have to actually look up a user to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a subset of [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50942074/3482140), you can get the properties of the `User` class by using FindClass() method of the schema instance.

Please find the below code which achieves what you want:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(
        "LDAP://CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=local",
        null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

ActiveDirectorySchema schema = ActiveDirectorySchema.GetCurrentSchema();

// below code retrieves Active Directory Domain Services class "User" in the schema.
ActiveDirectorySchemaClass user = schema.FindClass("User");

foreach (ActiveDirectorySchemaProperty property in user.GetAllProperties())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", property.Name);
}
```

You can get more details about [attributes of User class on Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ADSchema/c-user).

Comment: @Ultratrunks - Good to know! You may like to upvote the answer as well, if it helped you. See how to upvote an answer -> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow