# LdapConnection Active Directory schema information for user object

Tags: c#, active-directory, attributes, schema, ldapconnection

I am looking for method or search filters which can help me to get schema attribute information of user object from active directory over SSL.

I am using `LdapConnection` class to connect to the server. It is easy to get authenticate server.

Here is code for authenticating:

```
public bool Authenticate(string password)
{
        try
        {
            var credential = new NetworkCredential(UserName, password, Domain);
            var ldapServer = Domain;
            var ldapConnection = new LdapConnection(ldapServer);
            ldapConnection.Bind(credential);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return false;
        }

        return false;
}
```

It returns a success result.

My requirements is to get all schema attribute of user object present in Active Directory using `LdapConnection` search request.

`DirectoryEntry` or `PrincipalContext` is easy to user get schema information but in my case I need all information over only `LdapConnection` class.

This is how I search user but this is method to get user information I need only schema information also this method returns only those attribute which has value.

```
LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection(ldapServer);
connection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
connection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate = (ldapConnection, certificate) => true;
connection.AuthType = AuthType.Negotiate;

NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
connection.Credential = credential;
connection.Bind();

string filter = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=user) (sAMAccountName={0}))", LdapEncode(username));
var attributes = new[] { "sAMAccountName", "displayName", "mail" };

SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(baseDn, filter, SearchScope.Subtree, attributes);

var searchResponse = (SearchResponse)connection.SendRequest(searchRequest);

if (searchResponse?.ResultCode == ResultCode.Success)
{
    var entry = searchResponse.Entries[0];
    var model = new LdapUserModel
                {
                    Identity = GetStringValue(entry, "sAMAccountName"),
                    Email = GetStringValue(entry, "mail"),
                    Username = GetStringValue(entry, "sAMAccountName"),
                };

    return model;
}
```

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50935332/how-to-get-list-of-classes-of-an-active-directory-in-c-sharp/50942074#50942074

Comment: DirectoryEntry and PrincipalContext is helpless for solution

Comment: What you want is not possible; you will have to rely on DirectoryEntry class! May I know why you're refraining to use DE class?

Comment: This is the question why it is not possible

Comment: This isn't for `LdapConnection`, but there is an example [here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=kGApqjobEfsC&pg=PA266&lpg=PA266&dq=directoryentry+schemaentry&source=bl&ots=p7ruVaVPS6&sig=ACfU3U0G_hJZc4cULmrQfcyM_-jMettP_A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiKscjz-4viAhUDRK0KHYMvDNcQ6AEwA3oECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=directoryentry%20schemaentry&f=false) of how you can do it with `DirectoryEntry`. It works by calling into the `OptionalProperties` and `MandatoryProperties` methods of the Windows native [IADsClass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/iads/nn-iads-iadsclass) interface.

Comment: Any example to get user object schema properties only?